# What is the priority between ssh key types on a ssh connection?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, openssh, plink

While developing a ssh tool that connects to a sever I have seen the following:

In Windows(with plink), it uses the `ssh-ed25519` server key type to make the handshake and confirm it's fingerprint. In the other hand, in Ubuntu after a ssh command it uses the `ECDSA` server key type.

Windows:

```
The server's ssh-ed25519 key fingerprint is:
ssh-ed25519 255 xx:0e:84:ce:ca:ac:2f:e0:e8:f2:0a:fb:0e:a0:xx:xx
```

Ubuntu:

```
ECDSA key fingerprint is MD5:xx:69:68:81:bd:9b:a0:6d:23:31:91:1d:be:71:xx:xx.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
```

The server contains multiple ssh key types in /etc/ssh and I know that you can force to use a concrete type by uncommenting, for example, `HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key` in sshd_config. But my question is; Why Windows uses a different one than Ubuntu by default and viceversa? Is it because the client configuration of plink/openssh or on the server side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PuTTY clients use the order defined in the *Connection → SSH → Host keys* settings item, which defaults to this order:

```
Ed25519
Ed448
ECDSA
RSA
DSA
```

The single "ECDSA" item covers all `ecdsa-sha2-nistp*` algorithms. I'm not entirely sure of the internal order, but a server will usually never offer more than one variant anyway, so it is not important.

The OpenSSH `ssh` client uses the order defined by `HostKeyAlgorithms`, which defaults to approximately:

```
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,
ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,
ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,
ssh-ed25519,
rsa-sha2-512,
rsa-sha2-256,
ssh-rsa
```

(I've removed all `-cert` and `-sk` algorithms for clarity – nobody uses those, but the global order is the same anyway. The entire list is defined as KEX_DEFAULT_PK_ALG in myproposal.h in the source tree. The order hasn't really changed since 2013 when Ed25519 support was first added, although rsa-sha2 was added and ssh-dss was removed.)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

All algorithms involved in SSH connection, including the host key type is selected by the same process:

- First the server and the client exchange lists of algorithms they support
- And then one party (in this case the client) picks out of commonly supported algorithms the one it prefers.

PuTTY prefers the Ed25519. OpenSSH prefers ECDSA. In both the order of preferred host key types is configurable.